# Documents required for visiting Canada for an onsite job interview

Tags: canada, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, proof-of-employment

I want to visit Canada for an on-site job interview in a tech company. I am currently in Bangalore, India. I already gave my resignation notice at my current job as a software engineer, and I am still serving out the notice period which ends in one month.

From the [Visit Canada website](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/), I know that I need a visitor visa, which requires "Proof of Means of Financial Support (required)."

Since I'm serving out my notice period, my employer might not be willing to give me an employment letter. Since I won't be employed in a month, which option should I chose, that I have a job currently, or that I don't have a job?

What do I need to provide to satisfy the employment letter requirement: is the letter of employment mandatory in my case?

I have following documents:

1. Bank statement of past four months, of salary account.
2. Resignation e-mail with confirmation.
3. Initial job offer letter from the current employer.
4. Pay stubs.
5. Proof of accommodation fees.

Can I provide a copy of above 5 documents and also attach letter stating that I have recently resigned from my job, hence, could not provide employment letter?

Comment: Why did you decide to resign from your old job before you got the new one?

Comment: If you are still working on the date of applying for the visa, you should say that you have a job. If the visa is still in process and you reach the end of your notice period, you should inform the Government of Canada about the change. Also leaving a job before you get a new one is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Is the company you are interviewing with paying you expenses?

Comment: Does "Initial job offer letter from the current employer." mean the employer who has invited you for the interview, or the one you just resigned from?

Comment: Users can always comment on their own questions and on answers to those questions.  You have created multiple accounts; you can learn about merging them at https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts.

Comment: By resigning you seriously damaged your chances of getting this visa. You have removed your main tie back to India, making it more likely Canada suspects you will not return there. You also have no means to support yourself while you wait for the interview visa, and while you wait for your new employer to arrange a work visa. Which also leads CIC to think you might be planning on not returning.

Comment: Even if you're working out your notice, your employer should still be willing to write a letter saying "Mahesh works for us until date X."

Answer (score 2):

Why not state the truth, explaining the situation exactly as you have here: you have resigned, are working during the notice period, and will attend a job interview during your visit to Canada. Make it clear you understand what is permissable on a visit visa, that you may attend an interview but not work, that you have sufficient finances, and that you are to leave Canada before an entry with a work visa, should that be issued in future.

As for your documents, you can include the resignation email and the confirmation; it supports what you're saying, and clarifies why your current employer may be unwilling to provide any evidence of leave or employment. The old job offer letter is unnecessary, and irrelevant. More importantly, include any supporting communications, documents, or information from or about the Canadian company with which you will interview.